# Abstract and concrete method with same signature in generic class

Tags: java

In [JLS 8, Section 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) there is a statement:

> *A concrete method in a generic superclass C can, under certain parameterizations, have
>   the same signature as an abstract method in that class. In this case, the concrete method
>   is inherited and the abstract method is not. The inherited
>   method should then be considered to override its abstract peer from C.*

Could anyone provide an example of such parametrization for generic class? I was not able to.

Comment: It's on page 244 in the bottom. Provided quote is slightly modified to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
public abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract void m(T t);

    public void m(String s) {}
}

public class B extends A<String> {
}
```

In this case both methods in `B` will be `void m(String)`.

Comment: this looks like an appropriate example, i tried more complex ones and they did not worked :) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct given by @Roman, I want to add one more thing to that answer. If we change the parameter of method *m()* from `String to Object`, then there will be compilation error, because Generics works on Type erasure, so after type erasure `m(T t) -> will be to m(Object t)`, which is compilation error because we cannot have two methods with same name and signature. See below compilation error -

```
public abstract class A<T> {
    public abstract void m(T t); // compilation error: m(T) and m(Object), both method have same erasure

    public void m(Object s) {}
}

public class B extends A<Object> {
     @Override
    public void m(Object o) {
    }
}
```